# ios CoreData delete nth object

Tags: core-data, ios7

I have a simple iOS7 CoreData application with a single entity.
The entity is only supposed to store last 100 records.
When I add the 101th record - I want to delete the oldest record so that I always keep 100 (or less) records

How do I delete the "nth record"?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
  NSError *error;

//clear job: delete the old records before inserting new ones
NSFetchRequest *del_fetchRequest = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[del_fetchRequest setEntity: [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"News" inManagedObjectContext:_context]];


[del_fetchRequest setPredicate: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"(RecordID< %@)", number_here]];


NSArray *del_newsMatchingTitle = [_context executeFetchRequest:del_fetchRequest error:&error];

for (NSManagedObject *managedObject in del_newsMatchingTitle) {
    [_context deleteObject:managedObject];
    //NSLog(@"%@ object deleted",managedObject);
}
if (![_context save:&error]) {
    // NSLog(@"Error deleting %@ - error:%@",del_fetchRequest,error);
}
```